# How to disable back gesture in iOS 7 for only one view

Tags: ios7, gesture, back

I am trying to disable the back gesture for my view controller using the following set of code.

In `FirstViewController.m`, I'm setting the delegate of `interactivePopGestureRecognizer`

```
- (void) viewWillLoad {

    // Other stuff..
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
}
```

And then implementing the `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` method and returning `NO`.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

     return NO;
}
```

And in dealloc I'm setting the delegate to nil. (I have read somewhere that in iOS 7, you have to manually set the delegates to nil)

```
- (void)dealloc {

    self.navigationController.delegate = nil;
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = nil;
}
```

This works in the `FirstViewController`. But when I push `SecondViewController` to this, the gesture does not work on that either. How can I disable the gesture in FirstViewController only?

Also when I pop `FirstViewController` to go to `RootViewController` and then try to push `FirstViewController` again, I get the object deallocated error :

```
[FirstViewController gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x14ed0280
```

Why else do I need to do other than setting the delegates to nil? Or am I setting it in the wrong place?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try the below untested code in your FirstViewController :

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: Adding this code, disables interactions on all elements inside SecondViewController when I try to do a back gesture. Why is that??

Comment: Dude `self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;` works fine for me, try to remove the delegates.

Comment: ah sorry i forgot a bout super, i updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled` worked. But it is not working in my FirstViewController. Looks like there is some other issue. hmm..

Comment: Are you sure you are implementing view>Will<Disappear rather than viewDidDisappear? If you are re-enabling the gesture recogniser in viewDidDisappear, self.navigationController will be nil and so it won't be able to re-enable it.

Comment: It is also worth nothing that the view controller may not be part of the navigation controller's view hierarchy until viewDidAppear: is called. 

I recommend disabling the gesture recogniser in viewDidAppear:, and re-enabling it in viewWillDisappear:. These two methods, assuming your view controller is part of a navigation controller, should be able to access self.navigationController.

Comment: Works for me in iOS 7 and 8

Answer (score 17):

I originally put these answers into a comment below the accepted answer, but I feel this needs to be said as an answer to get more visibility.

More often than not, you will find that the accepted answer does not work. This is because `viewWillAppear:` can be called before the view is added to a navigation controller's view hierarchy, and so `self.navigationController` is going to be `nil`. Because of this, the interactivePopGestureRecognizer may not be disabled in some cases. You're better off calling it in `viewDidAppear:` instead.

Here's code that will work (assuming your view controller is correctly added to a navigation controller's view hierarchy):

### Objective-C

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[[self navigationController] interactivePopGestureRecognizer] setEnabled:NO];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[[self navigationController] interactivePopGestureRecognizer] setEnabled:YES];
}
```

### Swift

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: you're a wizard John

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.
iOS 12, swift 4.2

Answer (score 3):

I tried the all above but they did not work for me.So i tried this and it works for me on both IOS7 and IOS8.
 
    
 Just make sure that your view controller implements this protocol i.e ***UIGestureRecognizerDelegate***
and write the code given below.

> -(void)viewWillAppear : (BOOL) animated {
>
> ```
> [super viewWillAppear : animated];
>
> if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
>
>     self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled =
> ```
>
> NO;
>           self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate =
>   self; 
>       }
>
> }
>
> -(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
>
> ```
> if ([gestureRecognizer isEqual:self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer]) {
>
>     return NO;
>
> } else {
>
>     return YES;
>
> }
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

I found out setting the gesture to disabled only doesn't always work. It does work, but for me it only did after I once used the backgesture. Second time it wouldn't trigger the backgesture. Furthermore, as John Rogers said, it's import to use the viewDidAppear and viewWillAppear as the navigationController else would be nil.

Fix for me was to delegate the gesture and implement the shouldbegin method to return NO:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Disable iOS 7 back gesture
    if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    }
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    // Enable iOS 7 back gesture
    if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = nil;
    }
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This just worked for me in xCode 7:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController!.interactivePopGestureRecognizer!.enabled = false

}
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController!.interactivePopGestureRecognizer!.enabled = true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For only one view, I don't know the way... But I use the next code to disable fully the swipe gesture:

in your AppDelegate.m

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 7){
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    }
```