# iOS 7 disable the swipe back

Tags: ios, gesture

In iOS apps, there is a default gesture that swipe from the left edge to right the app `navigationController` will pop view controller.

But is there a way to disable it for specific view?

Comment: iOS Apps changing default gesture actions will not be accepted to the App Store

Comment: Look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108601/how-to-disable-back-gesture-in-ios-7-for-only-one-view). This may help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable back swipe gesture in UINavigationController on iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209468/how-to-disable-back-swipe-gesture-in-uinavigationcontroller-on-ios-7)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can disable it through the public API, See [UINavigationController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/interactivePopGestureRecognizer)

```
  //iOS7 Customization, swipe to pop gesture
  if ([navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
      navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
  }
```

Also, you can switch back to previous state when needed

Comment: I put it in the appDelegate, and works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

```
if(navigationController) {
  if ([navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
    navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its possible but may be a cause for you app rejection

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}
```